# Enabling Hibernate on Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hibernate

I have Linux Mint 19.1 on my laptop running on a Core i3 with 4GB RAM.
Setup of partitions is as per attached snapshot:  [partition setup - gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2swW.png)

I would like to know how I can enable hibernate. I have gone through the post https://superuser.com/a/1308719/191202 but not sure how I can setup the swap.

Comment: You would need to carve at least 4 GB out of SDA3 (8 GB would be better for normal swap use, but 4 GB is the minimum you need for hibernation).  I've never shrunken an encrypted partition, so I don't know what's involved.  But that freed space would be used for a swap partition.

Answer (score -1):

I am a bit late for the party, but I just made a [little guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602406/guide-on-how-to-enable-hibernation-on-linux-mint-20-cinnamon-ubuntu-20-and-pre) to help. Hope it works!

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Good idea! I have updated my guide, thank you!

Comment: {sigh} The essential stuff needs to be **in the answer** not in your guide.

Comment: Oh, that is what you meant. But then I would have to copy paste the whole thing. The person has the same setup I do, and all the steps are essential. Is that okay?