# What size swap partition will allow a Mint 19.3 installation with 64G RAM to hibernate?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hibernate, swap, swap-file

This same basic question is asked at [How can I enable hibernation under Linux Mint 18.3?](https://superuser.com/questions/1307353/how-can-i-enable-hibernation-under-linux-mint-18-3#1308719), but the question as asked only tells how much space is desirable for a 4Gi installation, and conflicting opinions address whether on the one hand you need enough space to handle swapping needs and additionally need space for a stored copy of memory contents, while another opinion is that you only need space for a stored copy of your memory contents.

I have had difficulties getting hibernation to work with recent versions of Linux Mint; on 19.3, I have never gotten a system with 16G RAM to hibernate, and that includes allocating 64G to the swap space.

How can I know what space is adequate for hibernation on a machine with 64G RAM?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Community Help Wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) on the subject  says 72 GB or more, and the [RedHat 7 help page on swap](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-swapspace#tb-recommended-system-swap-space) says 1.5x your RAM.